# Doxygen: XML Output for Groups Missing References to Other Types

Tags: doxygen

I'm working with Doxygen XML output. The project I inherited uses groups. I noticed that the XML output for the group doesn't contain refid attributes for other types. The output in the namespace code DOES contain the references.

Is there a Doxygen attribute that will emit the references for the types?

Alternatively, how can I find the correct type in the namespace XML file?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you give a small example (code, changes in the doxygen configuration file and the plaves in the XML wheer you have the problem)?

Comment: I'm running 1.8.14. If you like, I can cobble together a sample. The code in question is proprietary. I am output XML successfully. The problem is that the group XML file doesn't have refid's, which cross reference to the type of the parameter or return value. As near as I can tell, it has always been this way -- no changes were made to the doxygen configuration file.

Comment: The 1.8.14 version is from December 2017, we are now at version 1.8.17. There have been changes (also in the current github master), also in the XML writer part. So you can try the current master from github or to create a small problem so the problem can be reproduced. (you wrote "no changes were made to the doxygen configuration file" well I think at least `GENERATE_XML` has been set to `YES` ;-) )

Comment: Thank you. I'll try version 1.8.17. I meant that I made no additional changes to the doxygen config file that I inherited. And, yes GENERATE_XML is set to YES.

Comment: I updated my doxygen to 1.8.17 and ran my project. The refid elements are missing from the group output XML. Any other thoughts?

Comment: 2 thoughts: 1) try also the master version of doxygen; 2)  an example showing the problem